# Complex SQL JOIN Query, min, max and date range

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq, entity-framework

I have the following tables:

```
Readings:
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+
| Id |   TimestampLocal    | Value | Meter_Id |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | 2014-08-22 18:05:03 | 50.5  |        1 |
|  2 | 2013-08-12 14:02:09 | 30.2  |        1 |
+----+---------------------+-------+----------+

Meters:
+----+--------+
| Id | Number |
+----+--------+
|  1 |  32223 |
+----+--------+
```

I need to select 2 readings for each meter, the reading with max DateTime and the reading with min DateTime, in addition to the difference between values of the two readings, something like this:

```
+----------+------------+----------------+------------+----------------+------------+
| Meter_Id | MaxReading | MaxReadingTime | MinReading | MinReadingTime | Difference |
+----------+------------+----------------+------------+----------------+------------+
```

I need a single query to achieve this for all meters within a date range in Entity Framework

i was able to get this far (get max and min readings):

```
SELECT 
    tt.*
FROM Readings tt
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        Meter_Id, 
        MAX(TimeStampLocal) AS MaxDateTime, 
        MIN(TimeStampLocal) AS MinDateTime
    FROM Readings 
    where TimeStampLocal > '2014-12-08'
    GROUP BY Meter_Id
    ) AS groupedtt 
ON (tt.Meter_Id = groupedtt.Meter_Id)   AND 
    (tt.TimeStampLocal = groupedtt.MaxDateTime or tt.TimeStampLocal = groupedtt.MinDateTime) 
order by Meter_Id;
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: i was able to get min and max readings but i can't figure out how to do the calculation.

Comment: You are looking forward to implementing a linq or an sql query?

Comment: Linq, but if i could implement it in SQL i have no problem converting it to linq, i'll find a way

Comment: Show the code you tried nonetheless. Should `MaxReading` and `MaxReadingTime` be related? (i.e. the time of the max. reading)

Comment: yes it's the DateTime of the max reading (same record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this mockup of your actual schema and data:

```
class Reading
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimestampLocal { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int Meter_Id { get; set; }
}

List<Reading> Readings = new List<Reading>()
{
    new Reading { Id = 1, TimestampLocal = new DateTime(2014, 8, 22), Value = 50.5, Meter_Id = 1 },
    new Reading { Id = 2, TimestampLocal = new DateTime(2013, 8, 12), Value = 30.2, Meter_Id = 1 },
    new Reading { Id = 3, TimestampLocal = new DateTime(2013, 9, 12), Value = 35.2, Meter_Id = 1 }
};
```

using this linq query:

```
        var q = from r in Readings
                group r by r.Meter_Id into rGroup
                select new
                {
                    Meter_Id = rGroup.Key,
                    MaxReading = rGroup.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimestampLocal).First().Id,
                    MaxReadingTime = rGroup.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimestampLocal).First().TimestampLocal,
                    MinReading = rGroup.OrderBy(x => x.TimestampLocal).First().Id,
                    MinReadingTime = rGroup.OrderBy(x => x.TimestampLocal).First().TimestampLocal,
                    Difference = rGroup.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimestampLocal).First().Value -
                                 rGroup.OrderBy(x => x.TimestampLocal).First().Value
                };
```

produces this output:

```
[0] = { Meter_Id = 1, MaxReading = 1, MaxReadingTime = {22/8/2014 12:00:00 πμ}, 
        MinReading = 2, MinReadingTime = {12/8/2013 12:00:00 πμ}, Difference = 20.3 }
```

which should be close to expected result.

**EDIT:**

You can considerably simplify the above linq query by making use of the `let` clause:

```
var q = from r in Readings
        group r by r.Meter_Id into rGroup
        let MaxReading = rGroup.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimestampLocal).First()
        let MinReading = rGroup.OrderBy(x => x.TimestampLocal).First()
        select new
        {
            Meter_Id = rGroup.Key,
            MaxReading = MaxReading.Id,
            MaxReadingTime = MaxReading.TimestampLocal,
            MinReading = MinReading.Id,
            MinReadingTime = MinReading.TimestampLocal,
            Difference = MaxReading.Value - MinReading.Value
        };
```

Comment: Sir you are a genius! , thank you so much, my only concern now .. will this generate a single query if i am querying a table with millions of readings? (IQueryable) ?

Comment: @Yazan Tommalieh Well, as far as efficiency is concerned i do not know if this is the best possible solution to obtain the required result set. You can use SQL Profiler or Entity Framework Profiler to see which SQL query was actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient, I admit, but that's the quickest I could come up with something without counter-verifying it myself.

```
SELECT m.Id AS Meter_Id, MaxReading, MaxReadingTime, MinReading, MinReadingTime, (MaxReading - MinReading) AS Difference
FROM Meters m
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(Value) MinReading, TimestampLocal AS MinReadingTime FROM Readings WHERE Meter_Id = m.Id) min
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(Value) MaxReading, TimestampLocal AS MaxReadingTime FROM Readings WHERE Meter_Id = m.Id) max
```

edit: formatting.